# How to block all accesses, except three IPs, to an absolute URL with htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to block all accesses, except three IPs, to an absolute URL with htaccess?

Example data:
http://subdomain.example.com/url/i/want/to/block
IPs:
10.10.10.10
10.10.10.11
10.10.10.12

This is my code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} http://subdomain.example.com/url/i/want/to/block
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=10.10.10.10
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=10.10.10.11
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=10.10.10.12
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [R=302,L]
```

and it's not working. I'm accessing the URL with any IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match `protocol` and port etc in `REQUEST_URI`. Have it this way:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =subdomain.example.com
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=10.10.10.10
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=10.10.10.11
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=10.10.10.12
RewriteRule ^url/i/want/to/block /index.php [R=302,L,NC]
```

Or using regex character class:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =subdomain.example.com
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^10\.10\.10\.1[0-2]$
RewriteRule ^url/i/want/to/block /index.php [R=302,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thk you for your comment. I forgot to mention that my url is a subdomain. Thats probably why the first solution allows access to the website from any IP and the second denies access to the website for every IP.

Comment: Yes! Thk you so much!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to up-vote your answer :\

Comment: You have enough reps now to upvote any answer. I upvoted your question :)